# Preorder traversing in Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, traversal

I ran into problem and can't figure it out why my method doesn't return object when found one? It's recursively traversing left side of the tree first and then the right side. The `println` statement prints when the customer was found but `return customer` is always `null`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    public Customer lookUpCustomer(String lastName, String firstName) {

    Customer customer;
    Customer foundCustomer = null;

    if (left != null) {

        customer = (Customer) left.getItem();

        if(customer.getLastName().equals(lastName) && customer.getFirstName().equals(firstName)) {
            System.out.println("Found customer: " + customer.toString());
            return customer;
            //foundCustomer = customer;             
        }
        left.lookUpCustomer(lastName, firstName);
    }
    if (right != null) {

        customer = (Customer) right.getItem();

        if(customer.getLastName().equals(lastName) && 
       customer.getFirstName().equals(firstName)) {
            System.out.println("Found customer: " + customer.toString());
            return customer;
            //foundCustomer = customer;         
        }   
        right.lookUpCustomer(lastName, firstName);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: When you call the method recursively, you don't use the return value for anything. Don't you think you should?

Comment: Also, don't you think the name comparison should be against the *current* node? Eliminates the duplicate code and ensures that names in root node is compared too.

Comment: @Andreas How would I do that? `customer=left.lookUpCustomer(lastName, firstName) ` like that?

Comment: Yes, and then return it immediately if not null. That's the point, right? To return the found customer?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, that's the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are always returning `null` to function calling the `lookUpCustomer` first time. Also you are not saving returned value from recursive calls of `lookUpCustomer` method.

To solve this return the found node. You can change your code as following:

```
public Customer lookUpCustomer(String lastName, String firstName) {

    Customer customer;
    Customer foundCustomer = null;

    if (left != null) {

        customer = (Customer) left.getItem();

        if(customer.getLastName().equals(lastName) && customer.getFirstName().equals(firstName)) {
            System.out.println("Found customer: " + customer.toString());
            return customer;
            //foundCustomer = customer;             
        }
        foundCustomer = left.lookUpCustomer(lastName, firstName);
    }
    if (foundCustomer==null && right != null) {

        customer = (Customer) right.getItem();

        if(customer.getLastName().equals(lastName) && 
       customer.getFirstName().equals(firstName)) {
            System.out.println("Found customer: " + customer.toString());
            return customer;
            //foundCustomer = customer;         
        }   
        foundCustomer  = right.lookUpCustomer(lastName, firstName);
    }

    return foundCustomer;
}
```